# SCR Bundle within Felix on Android

Tags: java, android, osgi, apache-felix, declarative-services

I'm embedding Apache Felix 5.4.0 implementation of OSGi framework within an Android app, together with a couple of standard Bundles (like EventAdmin, Log, SCR, etc.). I embedded and configured the framework with no problems, but when I dynamically install and start EventAdmin and SCR Bundles, then Android RunTime shows me the following INFO messages:

```
06-01 12:25:39.954 6754-7234/example.app I/art: Rejecting re-init on
 previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.apache.felix.eventadmin.impl.Configuration$2>
06-01 12:25:40.769 6754-7234/example.app I/art: Rejecting re-init on
 previously-failed class java.lang.Class<org.apache.felix.scr.impl.config.ConfigurationSupport>
```

Anyway, if I install a Bundle hosting Components providing no dependencies toward others, SCR activate it with no problems, so it seems to work correctly. On the other hand, if I install a Bundle hosting a single Component providing a dependency toward another single Component which is hosted within an already installed and running Bundle (all requirements are resolved, I checked it), SCR does not activate the first Component even if it should do that, and it is not correct.

I tried to embed the framework also within a pure Java application, and in that case all works perfectly.

This perhaps means that there is a compatibility problem within and the SCR and EventAdmin Bundles implemented by Apache? (http://felix.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

Any idea about the possible cause? Thanks a lot

Comment: Couldn't parse the second paragraph. SCR never starts bundles... what is the actual error?

Comment: Yes, of course, I mean if for example I install a Bundle hosting a Component which has a dependency toward a Component hosted by an already installed and running Bundle, then SCR never starts the first described Component. I'll edit the question with this explanation anyway

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I expect this error is something to do with the difference in classloading on Android vs standard Java. As you said, it works fine in Java. I'm not even sure whether Felix supports running on Android.

Comment: @NeilBartlett Yes, Apache says it is supported. See this [link](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-framework/apache-felix-framework-and-google-android.html). Anyway, I think is a classloader problem, too. Thank you for the help.